# how to access the device camera from webview of android application

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, webview, camera

I have an android app with a `WebView`, it is written in  `Java Script` and `Angular JS` code to access the `Camera` , I just load the URL in web view and had given camera access permission and read and write external storage permission, still it is not able to access the camera , I had browsed for this problem ,but didn't find the exact solution.

I just want to open the camera , when user click on take photo on his profile page which was written in  java script code , don't know when this will happen because I have base `URL` only which was loaded in web view.

How to let the user open the camera in this application? And also it should support from `Kitkat` onward, Can any one help me to figure out this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `openChooser` method when implement UIClient

```
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
 i.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);
 i.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), 111);
}
```

Comment: whats that valueCallback<Uri>  type what should i pass as a parameter